# Survival Analysis: having 10 year worth of data, but want to compare 2yr survival among different groups

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am currently working on a bone marrow transplant dataset, with up to 10 years of follow-up. I am trying to compare the 2yr survival rate among different sub groups, but I am a bit confused about the 'censoring' of the R's survival package. Should I truncate my dataset to the 2yr time point? ie. changing their survival period to 365*2 max, and use the survival status at 2yr as the 'censoring' feature?

I tried using the original data, surv time up to 10yrs, and 2yr survival status as 'censoring'. But it's giving me a very long tail after 2 yr. Also, I am curious if this would affect the comparison I am about to do?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a better question for Cross validate, since this is more of a stats questions and less of a programming question.

Comment: I don't think it would affect your conclusions about survival probabilities up to 2 years, since the baseline KM estimate would not be affected. The "long tail" is expected to be flat and extend out to the full 10 years since you have kept that information. I would probably have truncated the analysis at 2 years if that's your goal..